# I take a loan in the amount of 3500 HRK which I pay 75 HRK per month with a 3% interest on the remaining debt. When will I pay him back?

Tags: calculus, economics

I take a loan in the amount of 3500 HRK which I pay 75 HRK per month with a 3% interest on the remaining debt. When will I pay him back?

My attempt:

 The formule that I was given to me was this:
$$D_n = \text{debt after n mounths}$$
$$D_n=D_{n-1}\cdot(1,03) - 75$$
$$D_0=75$$
When I calculate this I see that debt is rising???
3500
3560.9
3592.727
3625.50881
3659.274074
3694.052297
3729.873865
3766.770081
3804.773184

Comment: 3% interest. So you should multiply by 1.03 not by 1.3.

Comment: Surely the interest rate is *3 per cent per year* as opposed to *per month*! The latter rate would amount to loan sharking.

Comment: For pay day loan companies, 3% per month would be cheap.  However, this doesn't mean that I disagree with you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little less than 50 mos.

```
>>> d = 3500
>>> def f(x): return x*1.0025 - 75
... 
>>> for k in range(40):
...     d = f(d)
... 
>>> d
716.6252315796193
>>> for k in range(10):
...     d = f(d)
... 
>>> d
-23.750234049532082
>>>
```